# How do i remove an ellipse while pressing the correct letter in a basic letter pressing game?

Tags: processing

I am a complete beginner to programming and this is for a processing class assignment, so apologies if this is really obvious. For this assignment I am making a simple game, circles float towards the top and you have to type the letter shown on the screen to pop one of them at a time. I got most of the sections of the program done except making it so one circle is removed with each correct letter stroke. How would I go about doing that?

```java
int l=97;
int s=0;
int visa = 0;

Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[20]; 

void setup(){
    size(640,360,P2D);

    for (int i = 0; i< bubbles.length; i++){ 
        bubbles [i] = new Bubble (random(40,40));
    }
}

void draw(){
    background(255);
    char c=char(l);
    fill(0, 102, 153);
    textSize(22);
    text("Press this letter:  "+c,160, 100);//text(stringdata, x, y, width, height)

    if(millis()< 300000000&&key==c)//30 seconds
    {
        l=int(random(97,122));s++;
    }//here is where the score gets added! s++
    //random(low, high)

    for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++){

        bubbles[i].display();
        bubbles[i].acsend();
        bubbles[i].top();
    }
}
```

```java
class Bubble{
    float x;
    float y;
    float diameter;
    float yspeed;

    Bubble(float tempD){
        x =  random(width);
        y = height;
        diameter = tempD;
        yspeed = random(0.5,1.5);
    }

    void display(){
        stroke(255);
        fill(60,120,200,100);
        ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
    }

    void acsend(){
        if (y > 0){
            y = y - yspeed;
            x = x + random(-0.5, 0.5);
        }
    }

    void top(){
        if (y < diameter/2){
            y = height;
            x = random(width);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to detect when the user presses a key, and then iterate over the bubbles to see which bubble it matches, and remove that bubble? Shamless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) is a tutorial on user input in Processing. You might want to [start with something simpler](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and get that working first. Can you create a simple program that displays the letters the user types? Then if you get stuck, you can ask a more specific question and include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the initial number of bubbles to a variable:

```java
Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[20]; 
int noOfBubbles = bubbles.length;
```

Use the [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html), to evaluate if the correct key was pressed.
Decrement the number of bubbles, increment the score and create a new random character:

```java
void keyPressed() {
    char c=char(l);
    if (key == c) {

        if (noOfBubbles > 0) {
            noOfBubbles --;
            s ++;
            l=int(random(97,122));
        }
    }
}
```

Draw only the number of bubbles which are left (`for (int i = 0; i < noOfBubbles; i++)`):

```java
void draw(){
    background(255);
    fill(0, 102, 153);

    textSize(22);
    char c=char(l);
    text("Press this letter:  "+c,160, 100);//text(stringdata, x, y, width, height)

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfBubbles; i++){

        bubbles[i].display();
        bubbles[i].acsend();
        bubbles[i].top();
    }
}
```